# zTree to explore files

Tags: javascript, jquery, ztree

Is there an easy way to convert a list of files, with full path, into ztree nodes?

For example

```
Folder_1/Folder_1_1/File_1_1_a.txt
Folder_1/Folder_1_1/File_1_1_b.txt
Folder_1/Folder_1_1/Folder_1_1_1/File_1_1_1_a.txt
Folder_2/Folder_2_1/File_2_1_a.txt
Folder_2/Folder_2_1/File_2_1_b.txt
```

I want to convert into this

```
-Folder_1
    |-Folder_1_1
        |-File_1_1_a.txt
        |-File_1_1_b.txt
        |-Folder_1_1_1
            |-File_1_1_1_a.txt
-Folder_2
    |-Folder_2_1
        |-File_2_1_a.txt
        |-File_2_1_b.txt
```